# Add dates before and after existing ones in JSON with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Tried to find a solution everywhere but struggling with it. I have got a JSON array:

```
[{"12/08/2020":"Wednesday"},{"13/08/2020":"Thursday"},{"14/08/2020":"Friday"}]
```

How can I add 2 (or more) dates before and after existing ones so it will look like:

```
[{"10/08/2020":"Monday"},{"11/08/2020":"Tuesday"},{"12/08/2020":"Wednesday"},{"13/08/2020":"Thursday"},{"14/08/2020":"Friday"},{"15/08/2020":"Saturday"},{"16/08/2020":"Sunday"}]
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepend using [`Array.prototype.unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) and append using [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), and generate the objects using the function `get(o, days)` defined below:

```js
const input = [{"12/08/2020":"Wednesday"},{"13/08/2020":"Thursday"},{"14/08/2020":"Friday"}];

function get(o, days) {
  const weekdays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
  const [dd, mm, yyyy] = Object.keys(o)[0].split('/');
  const date = new Date(`${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}`);

  date.setUTCDate(date.getUTCDate() + days);

  const key = `${
    `${date.getUTCDate()}`.padStart(2, '0')
  }/${
    `${(date.getUTCMonth() + 1)}`.padStart(2, '0')
  }/${
    date.getUTCFullYear()
  }`;
  const value = weekdays[date.getUTCDay()];

  return { [key]: value };
}

function prepend(array, count) {
  while (count-- > 0) {
    array.unshift(get(input[0], -1));
  }
}

function append(array, count) {
  while (count-- > 0) {
    array.push(get(input[input.length - 1], 1));
  }
}

prepend(input, 2);
append(input, 2);

console.log(input);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Patrick-Roberts. Is there any way to declare a number of dates instead of repeating twice or more input.unshift(get(input[0], -1)); and input.push(get(input[input.length - 1], 1)); ???